# Django exception: Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Order' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-forms

Apologies for the noob question. Also, seems like similar questions have been asked here already, however the answers are about initiating a form with request.POST, which isn't relevant to what I've run into.

So -

I have an Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model): <br/>
    tf = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And a corresponding form:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

A view for the Order object:

```
def process_order(request, pk):
    p = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
    form = OrderForm(p)

    return render_to_response('mytest/process_order.html', {
        'form': form,
        })
```

And, finally, the template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But When I place my browser at localhost:8000/process_order/1/ I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /process_order/1/

Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Order' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/process_order/1/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'Order' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     /home/ranmoshe/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in value_from_datadict, line 178
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or am I not supposed to use `form.to_p` with ModelForm?

Comment: No sooner did I post than I realized what I did wrong - in the view the form should be initialized with `form = OrderForm(instance=p)`.

This solves the problem.

Comment: Just to tidy up, you could either write that as an answer and mark it as 'accepted' or delete your question.

Comment: Spycho, I can't do that because I don't have the permission - I can only answer my own question in 7 days...

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't associated an OpenID with your account. You should be able to delete your own post unless there is a reason in here why you can't: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222)

Comment: Another possibility, if you want the post deleted, would be to flag it for moderator attention and explain.